# Adapting gSheet graphs when adding new lines

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, limit, google-query-language

I would like to create a graph using the top 5 rows of a table, the table is updated every time adding a line on top. If I select in the graph a given range - say A2:A5 -, when I add another line the range expands now to A2:A6.

How should I fix that? The range refuses to take an Index function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this needs to be solved with extra step where you yse QYERY or FILTER formula and then do your graph from it, because graphs do not support formula inputs. for example:

```
=QUERY(A2:A; "limit 5"; 0)
```